# Python: How can I obtain something in a list of list?

Tags: python, list

Currently I have the following list:

```
>>> a = list()
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> c = [4,5,6]
>>> d = [7, 8]
>>> a.append(b)
>>> a.append(c)
>>> a.append(d)
>>> del b, c, d
>>> print a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

1. I want to obtain the first item on b, c and d (value 1, 4 and 7). How could I do that in one line of code?
2. I want to obtain the remaining item on b, c and d (value 2, 3, 5, 6 and 8). How could I do that in one line of code?

Comment: Something like `zip(b,c)[0]` or `zip(*a)[0]`?

Comment: But how about 2nd one? Thanks

Comment: How about `[1]`? `zip(*a)` basically gives you the transposed matrix, so you can subscript it or iterate over the columns or whatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> zip(*a)[0]
(1, 4)
```

The `zip(*a)` is like a transpose function.

```
>>> zip(*a)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

The `[0]` indexes the first element.

```
>>> zip(*a)[0]
(1, 4)
```

The second problem is trickier - `zip` won't do the trick. Instead you need a list comprehension.

```
>>> [i for l in a for i in l[1:]]
[2, 3, 5, 6, 8]
```

Or if you don't need a flattened list, simply:

```
>>> [l[1:] for l in a]
[[2, 3], [5, 6], [8]]
```

Comment: But how about 2nd one? I tried zip(*a)[1:] but it doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: Thanks I think list is the solution

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
[lst[0] for lst in a]
```

It iterates over a and for every element (which is a list) it collects the first value.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to do this. This would be one:

```
>>> print [x[0] for x in a]
[1,4]
```

Or putting print inside the for loop:

```
>>> for x in a: print x[0],
1 4
```

The most basic way if you only want the first elements of the first two sublists:

```
>>> print a[0][0], a[1][0]
1 4
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with niklas B. answer `zip(b,c)[0]`, but, to give you more flexibility, if you don't know the number of sublists in the list, you can also try:

```
[el[0] for el in a]
```

and gives you all the first items in the sublists of a.

Comment: Which is basically `zip(*a)[0]`, only producing a list instead of a tuple